# How is LinkedTransferQueue supposed to be used?

Tags: java, concurrency

What's the scene to use this structure?

I read the doc, and couldn't find an application.

Why the producer wants to know that the record be received (instead of processed) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransferQueues are useful because they let you maintain some type of backpressure. By waiting for a consumer to start processing, you know that the queue isn't just building up indefinitely while the consumer is stalled.

It's very similar to unbuffered `chan`s in Go, and also shares the coordination logic benefit (e.g. we know that at transfer/take time, the producer and consumer are synchronized).